# Can I use Unicodes in regex engine dk.brics.automaton?

Tags: regex, unicode, automaton

I want to use Unicodes in my regular expressions.

For example, RegExp="\u0061" matches "a". But it seems dk.brics.automaton does not support this. It turned out matching "u0061". I also tried RegExp="\u0061" and RegExp="\\u0061". None would work.

If you have any experience with this tool, could you please give me some solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to circumvent this issue.

First, we can use Unicodes in the Java code, but it has to be created individually. E.g. `String str = "\u0061"+"b";` While `String str = "\u0061b";` does not work well.

Second, if we want read the strings from a text file, like test.txt containing "`\u0061b\u0063`", we have to (as far as I know) replace the Unicodes with corresponding symbols manually, because they are mixed. Then we can get `String str` with the value "abc".

Answer (score 0):

I have no experiences in *dk.brics.automaton*, but I guess everthing is said in the [FAQ](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/faq.html) and the [JavaDoc for the RegExp Class](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html?dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html).

As I understand it, you can use unicode characters, but you have to express them as character ("a") and not with the `\u0061` notation.

Comment: thanks, splash. After contacted with the author of this tool, I realized that maybe I should focus on the solution in Java. Then I tested RegExp="b"+"\u0061", it works. The trick is that "\u0061" should be created individually, not like "b\u0061". Then the left problem is how to make this tool read "b"+"\u0061" from a text file.